# What loop should I use for the Question posted down below?

Tags: c++

Question is how to get the program to ask for input until a valid choice (4-20) is given by the user? I just need to know how to repeat a question. So if a user inputs the wrong number then it will ask the user to input a valid number until the user enters a correct number between 4-20.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int num;        //integer for number
int roll;       //integer for roll
srand(time(0)); //seed random number generator

cout << "You are about to roll a single die" << endl; 
cout << "How many sided die would you like to roll(4-20)? "; 
cin >> num;
cin.ignore();


roll = 1 + rand() % num;        //mods random number
if (num >= 4 && num <= 20) {
    cout << "You rolled: " << endl;
    cout << roll << endl;
} 

else
{
    cout << "Please play again and enter a number between 4 and 20" << endl;
    cout << "Press RETURN to continue..."<<endl;
    cin.get(); 
    cout<<"Exiting"<<endl;

}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: while is probably the most natural but either do {} while () or while or even for() could be made to work. Regardless of the choice of loop you probably want to reorganize your code after you put the loop in.

Comment: Regardless of loop type, you shouldn't roll your dice before you know that they are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
while(1)
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between 4 and 20: ";
    cin >> num;
    
    if (num >= 4 && num <= 20)
    {
        //mods random number
        //do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `while` loop to keep on asking for input and have a `if` statement to `break` when it is between 4 and 20.